# react: использование нескольких экспортных функций в одном файле

Tags: reactjs, svg, typescript, импорт, export

у меня есть файл `icons.tsx` в который я хочу разместить svg коды картинок:

```
const Icon1 = () => (
    <svg width="16" height="16" viewBox="0 0 16 16" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    </svg>
)

export default Icon1;
```

и соответственно использовать:

```
import Icon1 from '../icons/'

<Icon1 />
```

Все работает замечательно, когда в файле только 1 функция, но когда я пытаюсь разместить несколько функций

```
export const Icon1 = () => (...)
export const Icon2 = () => (...)
export const Icon3 = () => (...)


import {Icon1, Icon2, Icon3} from '../icons/'

<Icon1 />
<Icon2 />
<Icon3 />
```

, то валятся ошибки

когда использую

```
export const Icon1 = () => ...
```

и

```
import Icon1 from './icons'
```

получаю `has no default export. Did you mean to use 'import { Icon1 } from "projects"' instead?`

когда использую

```
export default {Icon1, }
```

и

```
import {Icon1}
```

получаю `has no exported member 'Icon1'. Did you mean to use 'import Icon1 from "projects"' instead?`

Подскажите, что делаю не так и как реализовать корректно такую возможность

**P.S.**

такое использование svg файлов вместо `<img src = 'icon1.svg' />` необходимо, чтобы можно было через css менять цвета картинки, без этого `color` и `fill` не работают :(

но если опять таки я просто что-то делаю не так, то буду благодарен совету

Comment: «то валятся ошибки» — это викторина «угадай ошибку»?

Comment: Попробуйте сначала объявить `const Icon1 = () => (...)` и т.д. а потом в конце экспортировать всех

Comment: Кстати [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53732511/how-to-export-2-arrow-functions-on-react) обсуждалось что-то похожее, может поможет

Comment: @EzioMercer, не работает даже с 1, только если объявляю ее напрямую как default

Comment: А вы пишете так `export default {Icon1, Icon2, ...}` ? Я просто это имел ввиду, когда сказал "экспортировать всех". Ну и потом импортировать через `*`, конечно

Comment: @Alexey Ten - использую `export const Icon1 = () => ...` и `Icon1`, получаю `has no default export. Did you mean to use 'import { Icon1 } from "projects"' instead?`, Использую `export default {Icon1, }` и `import {Icon1}` получаю `has no exported member 'Icon1'. Did you mean to use 'import Icon1 from "projects"' instead?`

Comment: @EzioMercer, да, делал так, а затем import {Icon1, Icon2} from './icons' и получал `has no exported member 'Icon1'. Did you mean to use 'import Icon1 from "projects"' instead?`

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136787/discussion-between-eziomercer-and-zhihar).